# Update text in single textfield with multiple drop down boxes with javascript client side

Tags: javascript

EDIT:  Ok, I really want to get this so I've decided to simplify what I need.  I have one textbox that onclick updates a textfield.  Now, what I need it to do is when they click on a second dropdown it will update a portion of text in the same textfield.  Hope this helps.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--    

            function OnSelectionChanged(listBox) {
                var textInput = document.getElementById("dn");
                textInput.value = listBox.value;
            }


    //--></script>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
    </ul>
    <div id="main" class="view">
        <h1>Text</h1>
    <div id="intro"><h5>Text</h5>
    <div id="content"><h2>Text:</h2>
    <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  <form method="POST" action="submit" name="myForm"><fieldset>
   <legend>Text</legend>

   <label>[<a href="help.html" onclick="openWin(this.href); return false" title="Disposition Details Page">?</a>]
    Disposition Code<br />
    <select size="1" name="disposition" id="drp_dwn" onchange="OnSelectionChanged (this)">
     <option value="-1" selected>&mdash;&mdash;Select one&mdash;&mdash;</option>
     <option value="Text ">190</option>
     <option value="191">191</option>
     <option value="192">192</option>
     <option value="195">195</option>
     <option value="270">270</option>
     <option value="300">300</option>
     <option value="340">340</option>
     <option value="350">350</option>
     <option value="370">370</option>
     <option value="380">380</option>
     <option value="381">381</option>
     <option value="382">382</option>
     <option value="383">383</option>
     <option value="384">384</option>
     <option value="400">400</option>
     <option value="401">401</option>
     <option value="402">402</option>
     <option value="403">403</option>
    </select>
   </label>
      <label>[<a href="help.html#input3" onclick="openWin(this.href); return false" title="Help on filling out input #3.">?</a>]
    Cause Code<br />
    <select size="1" name="cause">
     <option value="-1" selected>&mdash;&mdash;Select one&mdash;&mdash;</option>
     <option value="">Cause - 190</option>
     <option value="B">Option B</option>
     <option value="C">Option C</option>
    </select>
   </label><br /><br />


   <label><!--[<a href="help.html#input7" onclick="openWin(this.href); return false" title="Help on filling out input #7.">?</a>] -->
    Disposition Narrative
    <textarea id="dn" rows="8" cols="30" name="dn"></textarea>
   </label>
```

Im still getting used to how stack overflow wants us to format the code but hopefully you guys can read it well enough to help find a solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: I think the code may be useful to see exactly which parts of the text field you are trying to change and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

All I can really give you at this point is

1. Attach onchange handlers to your drop downs.  Your handlers will
   add/replace the text.
2. Use regular expressions to replace text when dd2 and dd3 change.

If you can provide more details about the text you want to replace then someone will be able to help you with your regular expressions.